# Chrome devtools with nativescript-vue doesn't work

Tags: debugging, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have vue nativescript app and I want to debug it in chrome developer tools.

I run:

```
tns debug ios --bundle
```

and copied URL to chrome:

> To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
>   chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000

but I received blank page with dev tools. It seems it does not open my application. Console log in terminal prints "NativeScript debugger attached." so it should work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkJ3I.jpg

Regards